# Crashlytics - Stacktrace in Firebase logs is not readable

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, react-native-firebase

I just started using React Native Firebase and Crashlytics (version 6). When I call `firebase.crashlytics().recordError(error)` in a JS `catch` block I see errors similar to the following in the Firebase Crashlytics logs. Is this the expected behavior?

This error log does not have any useful information, so I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly. (I thought about creating this as a bug report, but this seems like either the expected behavior or user error).

Errors triggered:

[image: Firebase Crashlytics Logs]

Stack trace from one of the errors:

[image: Stack trace in Crashlytic log]

If this is the expected behavior, I will probably call it like this: `firebase.crashlytics().recordError(new Error('The error description');`. That way I know where the error was, since I won't be able to tell from the line number where the error was. The downside of this is that it won't show the actual error message, so I'd know where the error was, but not what the error was.

Overall React-Native Firebase is working great for me, so thanks for all the hard work (if you're part of the team)!

Comment: Unfortunately this is the minified JS bundle stack trace - there's currently no way to add source maps for JS stack traces on Crashlytics - the minified stack traces there are sent through by building a custom native iOS/Android stack frames.

Comment: Hi, DowntownDev. Have you resolved the issue? Have the same thing, logs in firebase totally not readable.

Answer (score 19):

You can manually generate a sourcemap and then use a package such as [source-map-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-cli) to find the actual (non-minified) code causing the issue.

To generate a sourcemap run (modify filenames as necessary):

```
react-native bundle --platform ios --entry-file index.js --dev false --bundle-output ./ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ./ios --sourcemap-output ~/Desktop/bundle.js.map
```

Then to find line number of the actual code causing the issue, from Terminal run:

```
source-map resolve bundle.js.map 158093 26
```

The filename and line number will be outputted along with an excerpt of the code.