# React Native Firebase - Crashlytics and Hermes - Unreadable stacktrace

Tags: reactjs, react-native, crashlytics, react-native-firebase, react-native-hermes

We are using [react-native-firebase Crashlytics](https://rnfirebase.io/crashlytics/usage) and we recently enabled [Hermes Engine](https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes). Since then, we didn't manage to decipher our errors stacktrace. Before that, this solution worked just fine for us: [Crashlytics - Stacktrace in Firebase logs is not readable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58459572/crashlytics-stacktrace-in-firebase-logs-is-not-readable)

We also tried this, but no success: [react-native source map of hermes bundle with firebase crashlytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67835466/react-native-source-map-of-hermes-bundle-with-firebase-crashlytics)

### Screenshots

**iOS:**

[image: iOS Crashlytics stacktrace]

**Android:**

[image]